# dataGridView hos go simulate a cell click

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `dataGridView` and I want to simulate that a cell that was clicked.

I want to do this using a button outside the table (a "Send button").

How can I access the **row and column** that was added?

I thought doing it with:

```
dataGridView_MyTable.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[index].Selected = true;
```

However, this didn't work.

Comment: "but it didn't work" what didn't work (expected vs. actual behavior)?

Comment: Thats not simulating a click, thats selecting an item, which do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I have a send button inside the table. Outside the table i have a new button "And & Send". I want that each time i press "And & Send" it will get for me the poisition of the "Send" button

Answer (score 1):

I manage to slove it.

This is what i wrote:

```
        Int32 GetNextRow = dataGridView_OverrideTable.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        dataGridView_OverrideTable_CellContentClick(dataGridView_OverrideTable, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(SEND_COLUMN_INDEX_IN_GRID, GetNextRow));
```